# Multiple references to another table, but I don't know how many

Tags: database-design, join, fields

I have two tables in a database, folowwing this model:

```
scientists : id (int) | name (varchar) | surname (varchar) | publications (int)
publications : id (int) | fulltext (varchar)
```

I would like to add a field to the `publications` table which refers to `scientists`' `id`, but I don't know how many `scientist`s will be reffered to (can be 0, 1 or any other positive number) in order to ease the count of publications for each scientist.

What are my options ? Is my approach wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a 0-many relationship.  This is usually referenced by a third table.

```
Publication_Scientists : Publication_Id (int) | Scientist_Id (int)
```

with 1:1 relationships back to the other two tables.  Preferably using something like an enforced foreign key.